# scrapy crawling multiple pages [3 levels] but scraped data not linking properly

Tags: python, arrays, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape 3 levels of data: Tv name -> season -> episodes. The issue I'm having is that I'm getting all the episodes, but the first two levels is not linking. For example season 1 has 5 episodes and season 2 have 10 episodes, the output I'm getting is saying season 2 has 15 episodes and season 1 nowhere to be found.

```
def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

#for each television show extract the url to get the seasons
        for sel in jsonresponse["tv"]:
            item = TV()
            item['tv_name'] = sel['title']
            item['tv_url'] = sel['url']

            request = Request(item['tv_url'], callback = self.parse_season_details)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request


    def parse_season_details(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        item = response.meta['item']

        for sel in jsonresponse["seasons"]:
            item['tv_season'] = sel['season_no']
            item['tv_season_url'] = sel['season_url']

            request = Request(item['tv_season_url'], callback = self.parse_episode_details)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

#okay I found my tv show, extracted number of seasons, now I'm going into each season to get the episode details

    def parse_episode_details(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        item = response.meta['item']

        for sel in jsonresponse["episodes"]:
            item['tv_episode_number'] = sel["ep"]
            item['tv_episode_name'] = sel['name']
            item['tv_episode_description'] = sel['description']
            yield item
```

However - the output I get is this (lets say season 1 has 2 eps and season 2 has 3 eps)

1. tvshow season2 ep1
2. tvshow season2 ep2
3. tvshow season2 ep1
4. tvshow season2 ep2
5. tvshow season2 ep3

I've done some debugging but it seems to be the order it is executed. For the 2nd level, season2 is the latest to be scraped and overwrites season1 and it gets passed onto third level which proceeds to extract episode details.

If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this it will be great appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instantiate a new item to yield each time.
Assuming `TV()` is an item class

```
class TV(Item):
    ....
```

Than you should have a separate `item = TV()` for each episode

If you want to pass data from top levels - pass the data itself and create an Item only when you actually yield it:

```
def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())

#for each television show extract the url to get the seasons
        for sel in jsonresponse["tv"]:

            request = Request(sel['url'], callback = self.parse_season_details)
            request.meta['tv_name'] = sel['title']
            request.meta['tv_url'] = sel['url']
            yield request
```

Comment: Yep TV() is the item class. I instantiated TV() in parse but that didn't fix the issue...
I then instantiated within parse_season_details and now season->episode is linking correctly!
However its missing data from the first level scrape in parse. 
Minor issue but not sure if it is my logic or limitation of scrapy.

Comment: Oh... now I get what you are trying to do. Don't pass `Item` on meta, pass a dictionary/specific of the data itself - and create the `Item` only on the bottom level. That will solve your problem